# Bootstrap additional button falsely displayed during field validation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation, jsp, button, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my Bootstrap webstite, when a validation error takes place, then apart from the validation button which I display, an extra bootstrap validation button is falsely displayed OVER THE RIGHT NAV ARROW and I cannot understand why. I cannot come up with an idea to remove it.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGtfW.png)

My Bootstrap validation controls are performed inside some Bootstrap vertical tabs.

This is my code which is responsible for displaying validation button ON THE LEFT OF THE PAGE:

```
                                <div class="profile_nav_tabs" id="profile_nav_tabs">
                                <% if ( WfGetWorkItemCmd.checkStatusShowWI( wfWi )) { %>
                                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs navtab-bg nav-justified">
                                        <% if(tabs!=null) {
                                            for(int i=0;i<tabs.length;i++) {
                                                TabConfig vTabConfig= tabs[i];
                                                String tabName = vTabConfig.getTabName();
                                                String tabURL = url;
                                                String tabRequestMapp = vTabConfig.getRequestMapping();
                                                if (!StringUtil.isEmpty( tabRequestMapp ))
                                                    tabURL = HttpUtil.getJSP_URL(request, response, tabRequestMapp );
                                                if ( tabURL == null ) tabURL = HttpUtil.getJSP_URL(request, response, RequestMappings_v5.WF_HTTP_CMD_SEND_RUN_WORK_ITEM_TABS );
                                                String tabDisplayName = HttpControlsUtil.getChangeTabDisplayName(pageBean, vTabConfig);
                                                boolean isTabError    = HttpControlsUtil.getChangeIsTabError(pageBean, vTabConfig, wfWi, procData );
                                                boolean isSelected    = tabName.equalsIgnoreCase(activeTab);
                                        %>
                                                <li <%= (isSelected? "class=\"active\"" : "") %>>
                                                    <a href="#tab<%= i %>" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">
                                                        <span><i class="<%= (isSelected? "mdi mdi-note-plus-outline" : "mdi mdi-checkbox-marked-circle-outline") %>"></i></span> <span><%=label(tabDisplayName)%><% if(isTabError){ %><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove red pull-right"></i> <% } %></span>
                                                    </a>

                                                </li>
                                            <% } %>

                                        <% } %>

                                    </ul>
                                <% } %>
                                </div>
```

and this is the code which is created when I perform Inspect element in my web browser:

[Browser Inpsect Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PKh9.png)

Any idea how will I remove this right button at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I removed class `glyphicon-remove` which was responsible for my error button and it worked.